# Django ModelForm widget overriding issues

Tags: django, django-forms

I've been having issues for the past few days with trying to get a model form to use a different widget than what is in the model. I'm trying to make a form that dynamically updates a list of channel options from Slack and I'm having problems getting it the form to work.

Model:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_id = models.CharField(editable=False, primary_key=True, max_length=30)
    access_token = models.CharField(max_length=128, editable=False)
    post_channel = models.CharField(max_length=21, default=None)
    approval_channel = models.CharField(max_length=21, default=None)
    last_edit = models.CharField(max_length=21, default=None)
    admin_only_approval = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    admin_only_edit = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Form attempt 1:

```
class TeamSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    post_channel = forms.ChoiceField()
    approval_channel = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TeamSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        slack = Slacker(kwargs['instance'].access_token)

        priv_ch = [(g['id'], g['name']) for g in slack.groups.list().body['groups'] if not g['is_archived']]
        pub_ch = [(c['id'], c['name']) for c in slack.channels.list().body['channels'] if not c['is_archived']]
        users = [(u['id'], u['profile']['real_name']) for u in slack.users.list().body['members'] if not u['deleted']]

        self.fields['post_channel'].widget.choices=tuple(pub_ch)
        self.fields['approval_channel'].widget.choices=tuple(pub_ch + priv_ch + users)

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['post_channel', 'approval_channel', 'admin_only_approval',
                  'admin_only_edit']
```

Every time the form is submitted, it says that the data is invalid and that the input for the choice fields were not one of the available options.

Form attempt 2:

```
class TeamSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TeamSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        slack = Slacker(kwargs['instance'].access_token)

        priv_ch = [(g['id'], g['name']) for g in slack.groups.list().body['groups'] if not g['is_archived']]
        pub_ch = [(c['id'], c['name']) for c in slack.channels.list().body['channels'] if not c['is_archived']]
        users = [(u['id'], u['profile']['real_name']) for u in slack.users.list().body['members'] if not u['deleted']]

        self.fields['post_channel'].widget = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tuple(pub_ch))
        self.fields['approval_channel'].widget = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tuple(pub_ch + priv_ch + users))

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['post_channel', 'approval_channel', 'admin_only_approval',
                  'admin_only_edit']
```

Form attempt 3:

```
class TeamSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TeamSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        slack = Slacker(kwargs['instance'].access_token)

        priv_ch = [(g['id'], g['name']) for g in slack.groups.list().body['groups'] if not g['is_archived']]
        pub_ch = [(c['id'], c['name']) for c in slack.channels.list().body['channels'] if not c['is_archived']]
        users = [(u['id'], u['profile']['real_name']) for u in slack.users.list().body['members'] if not u['deleted']]

        self.fields['post_channel'].widget.choices=tuple(pub_ch)
        self.fields['approval_channel'].widget.choices=tuple(pub_ch + priv_ch + users)

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['post_channel', 'approval_channel', 'admin_only_approval',
                  'admin_only_edit']
        widgets = {
            'post_channel':  forms.ChoiceField,
            'approval_channel': forms.ChoiceField
        }
```

attempt 2 and 3 didn't even allow for the page to render.

I've been trying the different options [in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) but it hasn't been all that useful.

Comment: bit of a 'what if' here, but try `self.fields['post_channel'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=tuple(pub_ch), label='Post Channel')`

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me

```
self.fields['post_channel'].widget = forms.Select(choices=tuple(pub_ch))
```